# Matlab stop function's execution

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, interrupt

I have an array. I am processing elements of this array in a for loop inside a function.

```
function results = processArray(array)
   for ii = 1:length(array)
      %some stuff here
      results(ii) = %getting the results for this particular element
   end
end
```

There might be a lot of elements and computations might take a lot of time. I want to be able to finish execution of the for loop at any arbitrary time when a user wants to do that so that the results for already processed elements would be available.

I was trying to make a figure with a button which would change a boolean flag. Inside the for loop I was checking the value of that boolean. If the boolean changed then the for loop should break.

```
function results = processArray(array)
   fig = figure;
   fig.UserData.continue = 1;
   uicontrol('Parent', fig', 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'stop', 'callback', @interrupt)

   for ii = 1:length(array)
      if(fig.UserData.continue == 0)
         break;
      end
      %some stuff here
      results(ii) = %getting the results for this particular element
   end
end

function interrupt(obj, ~)
   fig = obj.Parent;
   fig.UserData.continue = 0;
end
```

well, that does not work. The figure shows up only after all the computations are done already. If I draw the figure first using something like waitforbuttonpress and proceed to the for loop pressing the button does not stop the execution. I think the callback function is being executed only after the for loop is finished. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `return` instead of `break`?

Comment: no I have not used return instead of break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to `drawnow` after you create the button, so it will show up. You also need to `drawnow` within the loop to update the button state. Then you should achieve what you want.

`drawnow` force figure update, so it will slow down your computation a little.